# Transfering a game from Python to C

Tags: python, c

I have a simple game [RiceRocks](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user7-hENkYFJC0jMxjw8.py) which I want to translate into C programming language not C++,because I know C better. I know only basic C++ such as : loops,control statements, arrays.
Where to start? What library should I use?

Comment: This is fundamentally a hybrid "what tool should I use" and a "how do I get started" type of question, both of which have been deemed not useful on this site. If you google around for 2D game libs in C, you'll find there are plenty to choose from that are great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some knowledge of C and Python, the code shouldn't be hard to port. The only thing missing from the standard C which you need to write the game, is a graphics library. As you can see, the Python implementation uses something called `simplegui` which creates the window, loads images and then draws them. You can do this fairly easy in C using the SDL library. Here's a set of tutorials to help you get started: http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/

Oh, and you need to transform the classes into structures. Just place all the members of the class in a C struct, and implement each method as a function that gets a pointer to the struct ( just as the python methods get a reference to `self` as their first parameter ).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But are tutorials on lazy foo sutable for C? It seems that they are based on C++.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I remembered them being for C so I didn't double check. It seems the first 8 tutorials are only using C though, so they should be enough to help you get started.

Answer (score -4):

First off, saying "I know C better" is wrong because that doesn't sound right, and C is technically not better because it's missing a lot from C++ and it's not OOP which means classes and objects don't exist in it. Second off if I were you I would learn C or C++ until your great at it and then look into game libraries such as [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) or [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) or a C++ game engine like [Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I asked this question because my teacher want's me to translate this game into C. Ant I know the difference between C and C++. I just need some links on where to start.

Comment: "wrong because that doesn't sound right" is wrong because that doesn't sound right

Comment: so can someone help ?

Comment: @Adam Naylor I said "<place what he said here> is wrong because it doesn't sound right" which sounds just fine.

Comment: First of all, all the libraries you mentioned, and the OpenGL implementation are written in C. Second, he didn't say C was better he said hew knew C better. Third, answering with "is wrong because that doesn't sound right" is not an answer.

Comment: Converting an existing game from python to c or c++ is a great way to get "great" in c/c++ programming. I would prefere c++ over c for bigger projects, but this one should be just fine in c. Rootlocus' answer is good.

Comment: Usually when you port a program one-to-one from one language to the other and you don't know the target language as well as the source language, you end up trying to apply the design philosophy of the source language to the target language resulting in very awkward code.